# Variable file usage with Robot Framework and Python

Tags: python, robotframework

If I create a variable file `(var.py)` and start my robot test:

> robot --variablefile var.py[:set1] `.\test_this.robot`

How can I use this variables in my other file `(settings.py)` what is called from Robot Framework test?

The goal is to start test and enter the environment I want to use (get from var.py file) and use that selection in settings.py

Do I need to pass the selection with parameter when calling settings.py file or can I use/read the var.py file directly from settings.py?

Comment: Can you show us some code? how does your settings.py look?

Comment: Would you be open to a slightly different approach that uses a .py and .robot file combo?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using this in .robot
Run Keyword If   '${VAR}' == 'a'   Import Variables   ${CURDIR}/var_a.py

And this in .py
BuiltIn().get_variable_value('${DBHOST}')